Los mensajes en consola no aparecen, excepto uno por una fracción de segundos: WebSocket connection to <url> failed: Invalid frame header
Tengo un error en mi código js que es parte del proyecto flask; maneja el error y al eliminar un dato actualiza la página index.
Este es mi código donde se encuentra el error, pero los mensajes en consola no aparecen, excepto uno por una fracción de segundos:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/?EID=4&transport=websocket&sid=GMHSVvEWtJe_9QofAAB2' failed: Invalid frame header.

Este es mi código que maneja la eliminación de un dato y la actualización de la página; elimina el dato pero no actualiza la página:
  socket.on("connect_error", function(error) {
      console.log("Error de conexión:", error);
  });

  function deleteRow(button) {
      // Obtén el ID del paciente y la especialidad desde los atributos de datos del botón
      var patientId = button.dataset.id;
      var specialty = button.dataset.especialidad;

      console.log("Preparándose para emitir el evento de eliminación para el ID:", patientId); // Mensaje de registro

      // Emitir evento de Socket.IO con el ID del paciente
      socket.emit("delete data", { "id": patientId });
      console.log("Evento de eliminación emitido."); // Mensaje de registro
  }

  // Escuchar el evento de Socket.IO "delete data"
  socket.on('delete data', function(response) {
      console.log("Evento de eliminación recibido:", response); // Mensaje de registro

      if (response.success) {
          console.log(response.message); // Opcional: mostrar mensaje de éxito
          // Eliminar visualmente la fila de la tabla (opcional, también se puede hacer en el lado del servidor)
          $('#row-' + response.id).remove();
          console.log("Recargando la página después de la eliminación exitosa"); // Mensaje de registro
          // Recarga la página completa
          window.location.reload();
      } else {
          console.error(response.message); // Opcional: mostrar mensaje de error
      }
  });


Qué mensajes si quedan en la consola? veo que hay varios console.log en el código...
